# Write array to plist and fill tableview

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, nsmutablearray, plist

I have a method that returns a an NSMutableArray with a bunch of strings. How can I add this array (with strings) to a plist file and use it to fill an UITableView with it? Thanks

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"brochurenames" ofType:@"plist"];
    [[self returnBrochureNames] writeToFile:path atomically:YES]; < successful but I can't seem to read from it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create an array with Values

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"One",
                  @"Two",
                  @"Three",
                  @"Four", nil];
```

Create File Path in Document Directory, you can write file there, not in Application Bundle

```
NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentFolder = [path objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentFolder stringByAppendingFormat:@"myfile.plist"];
```

Save Array to Plist file

```
[array writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
NSLog(@"file Stored at %@",filePath);
```

To Read Array From plist Use Following Code

```
NSArray *plistArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSLog(@"%@",plistArray);
```

Though if you are still not getting you can refer tutorial [here](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/how-to-use-plist-in-iphone/)

Comment: Great, this really helped me! Thanks! edit: you should add a "/" in front of the file name to actually write it inside the documents folder.